# Find a limit for $\frac{({1+x})^\frac{1}{x} - e}{x}$ as x tends to 0

Tags: limits

I have done it thus far:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{{(x+1)}^\frac{1}{x}-e}{x} = \bigg[\frac{0}{0}\bigg] = \frac{((x+1)^\frac{1}{x}-e)'}{x'}=({x+1})^\frac{1}{x} \cdot \left(\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}\right)' = \\({x+1})^\frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{\left(\frac{x}{x+1}-(\ln(x+1)\right)}{x^2} = ({x+1})^\frac{1}{x} \cdot \left(\frac{\frac{1}{x+1}}{x} - \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2}\right) $$

I don't know what to do next.

Also could someone elaborate as to why when I have to find a derivative for $\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}$ I need to use the quotient rule, but when I first derived the fraction that is given I could derive numerator and denominator separately?

Comment: In regards to your last question, you are applying something called L'Hopital's rule if you differentiate numerator and denominator separately. This has nothing really to do with quotient rule, it helps you evaluate limits where your expression is indeterminate.

Comment: Two errors. 1. The indeterminate form is 0/0 not $\infty/\infty$ 2. No square in denominator

Comment: @ErotemeObelus Yes, but the OP has correctly differentiated it.

Comment: @PeterForeman my phone's screen is tiny so I didn't see the multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\frac{x}{x+1}-\ln{(x+1)}}{x^2}\right)
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{x-(x+1)(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+O(x^4))}{x^2(x+1)}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{-x^2+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}+O(x^4)}{x^3+x^2}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^4)}{x^3+x^2}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{-x+\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)}{3x^2+2x}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{-1+x+O(x^2)}{6x+2}\right)\\
&=-\frac12\\
\end{align}$$
Hence the initial limit becomes
$$\overbrace{\lim_{x\to0}\left((x+1)^\frac1x\right)}^{\large{\to\, e}}\cdot\overbrace{\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\frac{x}{x+1}-\ln{(x+1)}}{x^2}\right)}^{\large{\to\, -\frac12}}=-\frac{e}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

So, we apply L'Hôpital's rule,  and get $((1+x)^{\dfrac 1x})'=(e^{\ln(1+x)^{\dfrac 1x}})'=(e^{\ln(1+x)^{\dfrac1x}}\cdot(\dfrac 1x\ln(1+x))'=(1+x)^{\dfrac 1x}\cdot (-\dfrac 1{x^2}\ln(1+x)+\dfrac1x\dfrac 1{1+x})$.

Now the first term converges to $e$;  and the quantity in parentheses converges easily, upon a couple more applications of L'Hôpital to $-\dfrac 12$.

So we get $-\dfrac e2$.

Comment: How can you apply L'Hospital's rule if it's [ e * 0 ] ?

Comment: The quantity in parentheses is of the form $\dfrac00$ after you combine it into a single fraction.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compute the derivative of
$$
f(x)=(1+x)^{1/x}
$$
Consider $\log f(x)=\dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x}$ and
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{\dfrac{x}{1+x}-\log(1+x)}{x^2}
$$
so you have
$$
f'(x)=f(x)\frac{x-(1+x)\log(1+x)}{x^2(1+x)}
$$
Note also that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{f(x)}{1+x}=e$, so you need to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-(1+x)\log(1+x)}{x^2}
$$
With a further application of l'Hôpital,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-1-\log(1+x)}{2x}=-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$
Reinserting the factor $e$, the sought limit is $-e/2$.

Answer (score 0):

With binomial expansion 
$$\begin{align}
(1+x)^{\frac1x}-e 
&=1+\frac1x\frac{x}{1!}+\frac1x(\frac1x-1)\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac1x(\frac1x-1)(\frac1x-2)\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots-\left(1+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{1}{2!}+\dfrac{1}{3!}+\cdots\right)\\
\frac{(1+x)^{\frac1x}-e }{x}&=
-\dfrac{1}{2!}-\dfrac{3-2x}{3!}-\dfrac{6-11x+6x^2}{4!}+\cdots\\
&\to-\dfrac{1}{2!}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{1}{2!}+\cdots\right)\hspace{1cm}\text{as}\hspace{0.3cm} x\to0.\\
&=-\dfrac12e
\end{align}$$